# How can I solve this problem I am currently using random.choices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import random

GENDER = ["F", "M"]
gender_type = random.choice(GENDER)
print(gender_type)
```

how can I make sure that the female and male gender type both comes up same amount of times e.g.

```
NO_OF_FEMALES =100
NO_OF_MALES = 100
```

with the `random.choice` I cant guarantee that F and M will come up 100 times each

Comment: Generate a list with 100 of each type, `random.shuffle()` the list, then iterate through it to get a random ordering with the correct exact proportion.

Comment: If it has to be 50:50 why make it random?

Comment: You could also multiply the list by the random number you generated and then shuffle that

Comment: @jonrsharpe An example might be the order of students standing in a line.  The total number of students is fixed, but the order in which they are dealt with would vary randomly.

Comment: @pjs would you be able to show me an example please I am still learning so finding it quite hard

Comment: `line = GENDER * 100; random.shuffle(line)`

Comment: @pjs yes, but I'm trying to understand what the *OP's* context is.

Comment: Don't know how to code *what*? What's the actual outcome you're looking for?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych  thats amazing!! thank you

Comment: ...and where does the randomness come in?

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you shuffle a deck of cards, they have one of 52! random orderings.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych  what if the number of females were 50 and males were 100 - would I be able to write this in the same line of code? line = GENDER * 100; random.shuffle(line)

Comment: If you understood what this line does, you would.

Comment: @Girl007 If you want 50 females and 100 males, use `['F'] * 50 + ['M'] * 100` in the solution I provided below.

Answer (score 1):

As pjs points out, the best way is to generate a list with 100 males and 100 females and then reorder it randomly. I think the best way would be the one Yevhen points out. That would look like this:

```
people_per_gender = 100
gender = ["M","F"]
people = 100*gender #at this point the list is ordered: M, F, M, F ...
random.shuffle(people) #now the list people is randomly ordered, use it for whatever you need

#check by printing first 10:
for i in range(10):
     print(people[i])
```

Comment: what if there are more males than females eg; male_people=100              female_people = 50 how would I specify this for each gender type  @Andrew M. Martin

Comment: For arbitrary numbers of males and females you could do the following: male_people = x; female_people = y; males = x * ['M'], females = y * ['F'], people = males + females; random.shuffle(people). And now people is a list with the specified amount of males and females in random order.

Answer (score 0):

I'll demo with a smaller set.

You're going to use randomness:

```
import random
```

Construct a list with 5 of each gender:

```
students = ['F'] * 5 + ['M'] * 5    # ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M']
random.shuffle(students)
print(students)  # yields ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M'] for example
```

Now do whatever it is you want to do with `students`.